# passing a pipe as an argument to sort -m

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I am wondering if it is possible to send multiple pipes lets say 3 as arguments to be merged with sort -m in c.

For example execvp("sort", "sort", "-m", pipe1_read_end, pipe2_read_end, NULL)

Comment: Well, it merges fine in a `bash` script with named pipes created by `mkfifo` and `sort -m pipe1 pipe2 pipe3 >sorted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is only targeting Linux, you can pass strings of the form:

```
/dev/fd/<number>
```

...representing your pipes, where `<number>` is, of course, the FD table entry number for the file descriptor in question. In fact, bash does this itself if you run

```
sort -m <(something) <(something)
```

For a more OS-agnostic solution, one typically uses named FIFOs (and this is what bash does with the `<()` construct if it detects that it's on an operating system that doesn't provide `/dev/fd/`).